# This JSON object cannot be converted to JSON array

Tags: android, json

I have tried everything and i can't covert this JSON object into JSON array, it throws JSON Exception

Here is Logcat:

> 11-13 11:19:53.964: W/System.err(8642):   at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
>   11-13 11:19:53.964: W/System.err(8642):     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:91)
>   11-13 11:19:53.964: W/System.err(8642):     at org.json.JSONArray.(JSONArray.java:103)

Here is the JSON file:

> {"GetGISResult":[{"Active":true,"CategoryID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreateUser":null,"Description_ar":"التا","Description_en":"هعلل","Email":"لتتالت","Lat":30.0764857,"Long":31.30658,"Mobile":"تالتال","SectionID":9,"SectionName_ar":"1","SectionName_en":"لاتا","UpdateDate":null,"UpdateUser":null},{"Active":true,"CategoryID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreateUser":null,"Description_ar":"التا","Description_en":"هعلل","Email":"لتتالت","Lat":30.0892124,"Long":31.2892342,"Mobile":"تالتال","SectionID":10,"SectionName_ar":"2","SectionName_en":"لاتا","UpdateDate":null,"UpdateUser":null},{"Active":true,"CategoryID":1,"CreateDate":null,"CreateUser":null,"Description_ar":"التا","Description_en":"هعلل","Email":"لتتالت","Lat":30.0433341,"Long":31.3006067,"Mobile":"تالتال","SectionID":15,"SectionName_ar":"7","SectionName_en":"لاتا","UpdateDate":null,"UpdateUser":null}]}

Here is my code:

```
try {
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                int responsecode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (responsecode == 200) {
                    InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    resultstring = convertinputStreamToString(in);

                    System.out.println("resultstring>>> "+resultstring);

                    try {

                        JSONArray stores = new JSONArray(resultstring);

                        for (int i = 0; i < stores.length(); ++i) {

                            JSONObject jo = (JSONObject) stores.get(i);
                            // TO-DO JSON here
                            result.add(convertToStores(jo));
                            Log.v("check on adding Lat to list", result.get(i)
                                    .getLat()+"");
                            Log.v("check on adding Lon to list", result.get(i)
                                    .getLong()+"");
                            Log.v("check on adding Description to list",
                                    result.get(i).getDescription_ar());
                            Log.v("check on adding Email to list",
                                    result.get(i).getEmail());
                            Log.v("check on adding Mobile to list", result
                                    .get(i).getMobile());

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException  c) {
                        Log.v("Exception >>>", c.getMessage().toString());
                        c.printStackTrace();

                    }
                    long total = 0;
                    byte data[] = new byte[1024];
                    while ((count = in.read(data)) != -1) {
                        total += count;
                        // publishing the progress....
                        // After this onProgressUpdate will be called
                        setProgress((int)((total*100)/1000));
                    }
                }else if(responsecode != 200){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your connection is break down please check your connection ..", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


public static String convertinputStreamToString(InputStream ists)
        throws IOException {
    if (ists != null) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        try {
            BufferedReader r1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    ists, "UTF-8"));
            while ((line = r1.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
        } finally {
            ists.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you plase post your error here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you have to create jsonObject for result.

```
    JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject(resultString);
    JSONArray array=jsonObj.getJSONArray("GetGISResult");
```

Answer (score 1):

your json parsing code is wrong. try below code:

```
JSONObject jsObject=new JSONObject(resultString);
JSONArray jsArry = jsObject.getJSONArray("GetGISResult");

for(int i=0; i<jsArry.length();i++){
        JSONObject jsOrderDataObject = jsArry.getJSONObject(i);

        jsOrderDataObject.getString("CategoryID");

        .......... and so on

}
```